# Can we use Tag Helpers in a Razor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, tag-helpers

Can we use Tag Helpers in a Razor component?

I cannot use Tag Helpers or HTML Helpers in a Razor file.

How do I import Tag Helpers?

```cs
<h3>Curent person @People.Skip(personIndex).First().FirstName</h3>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PreviousPerson" value="Previous Person"/> 
<input type="button" @onclick="NextPerson" value="Next Person"/>
 
@foreach (var item in @People) {
 <tr>
  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>            
  <td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.BusinessEntityId">Edit</a></td>
 </tr>
}
 
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<EcoleWeb.Areas.Persons.Models.PersonModel> People { get; set;}
    private int personIndex;

    private void NextPerson()
    {
        if (personIndex < People.Count() - 1)
            personIndex++;
    }
    private void PreviousPerson()
    {
        if (personIndex > 0)
            personIndex--;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TagHelper are not supported in Blazor, [For more information](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42607)

Answer (score 0):

> Integrating Razor components into Razor Pages and MVC apps in a hosted Blazor WebAssembly app is supported in ASP.NET Core in .NET 5.0 or later.

So you needs to make sure your version of project is .NET 5.0 or later firstly.

And then if you want to use tag helper in razor component,you need to add the following code:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

For more details,you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: TagHelper are not supported in Blazor, I'm talking about razor file (razor component)